# Using the l() function within a node description field

Tags: path-aliases

I'm converting an old site to Drupal, and I need to convert all the old URLs to the new system, which uses pathauto. I can turn the old links into node paths (eg. node/28), but I ideally want the aliased paths to show instead. I've found the l() function, but how do I go about applying it to links within the description field of nodes?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. You have converted all links in content to node/$nid - this is covered and works. Now you want to convert them to pathauto format, the one that would be returned by `l()`. Not only fields, but also links plain in content. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already turned old links into `node/28` format, you don't need to touch your content any more. You can simply use [Internal Links](https://drupal.org/project/intlinks) module that will replace it live with the current alias. The benefit is - with this module if alias changes, content still links to a node by node's id, and links stays valid.

> The Internal Links Title filter inserts HTML title attributes into links to other nodes on a site (if no title attribute already exists) using the linked node’s title as the HTML title attribute’s value. **It also replaces href values** which are in the “normal Drupal path” form (e.g. ) **with a URL alias**, if one exists.

Emphasis mine.